# OpenCL: Preferred Vector Width Vs Native Vector Width

Tags: opencl

A simple device query opencl program on my PC with intel N2820 cpu (having Intel HD Ghaphics), gives these lines:

```
CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_INT: 1
CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_LONG: 1
CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_FLOAT: 1
CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_DOUBLE:
CL_DEVICE_NATIVE_VECTOR_WIDTH_INT: 1
CL_DEVICE_NATIVE_VECTOR_WIDTH_LONG: 1
CL_DEVICE_NATIVE_VECTOR_WIDTH_FLOAT: 1
CL_DEVICE_NATIVE_VECTOR_WIDTH_DOUBLE: 0
```

Can someone explain what do we mean by proffered and native vector width for different data types?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The native vector width is the width that the hardware/ISA exposes. The preferred vector width is the width that the OpenCL implementation/compiler would *like* you to use. These two values won't necessarily be the same.

For example, on my Intel Xeon CPU with Intel's latest OpenCL implementation, I get the following values:

```
CL_DEVICE_NATIVE_VECTOR_WIDTH_FLOAT:    8
CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_FLOAT: 1
```

This tells me that the hardware has 8-wide 32-bit floating point vector ALUs (i.e. 256-bit AVX), but that I should write my kernels using scalar types (i.e. just `float`, not `float8`). This is because  the OpenCL compiler will pack work-items into SIMD lanes, and take advantage of the vector units automatically.

Comment: "8-wide 32-bit floating point vector ALUs" = "8 floating point vector ALU units"?

Comment: @user25108 By "8-wide" I mean that the vector ALU can process 8 elements at once.

Comment: But is it not logical that using float8 will be faster since I have enough hardware for processing it? How would simple float be better ?

Comment: It depends on the compiler. As I wrote in my answer, Intel's compiler will generally pack work-items into SIMD lanes, so it will be automatically taking advantage of the vector processing units.

Comment: when you say SIMD lanes, you mean Processor cores?

Comment: No, for the CPUs that I'm talking about, each 'core' has a vector unit that can process multiple `float` values at once (8, in this instance). When you compile and OpenCL kernel with Intel's latest OpenCL SDK, the compiler will aggregate multiple work-items into a single thread, so that it can process 8 work-items at a time using these vector units.

Comment: SIMD lanes = 'aggregated multiple work items'? what is that physically ?

Comment: Inside each core is a 256-bit vector unit, which can perform floating point operations from 8 different work-items simultaneously.